# I am trying to install and use ProtoBuf for Windows .NET C# and I am having problems

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I just installed protobuf for Java and that is working great.

I am now trying to install protobuf for .NET 4.0 for C# language.

First of all the protobuf website does not have any install instructions.

I downloaded the latest binaries, which are mostly dlls. 
Where do I put these dlls?

Also there is a protoc compiler but it only has an output option for C++, not C#.
Where is there a C# option?

I created a test file, which is an exact copy of the example on this page and I am getting errors(Error 1 - expected top level statement)?

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted

```
    [ProtoContract]
class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get;set:}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
class Address {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Line1 {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Line2 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Your sample is already C# code. With C# there are two options, one of which is "code first". Put that into your normal source code and compile.

Comment: the code to de/serialize might be worth seeing too.

Comment: Could you give an example of the .proto file I should try and the protoc command to get C# output. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download protobuf project from below link :

[Proto Buf C# project Download Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/2.0.0.666)

Install Package manager steps :
[enter link description here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c)

If Package manager is not available in you VS IDE. then down load from below link :
[Package manager console download link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

To generate protobuf Library for C#: follow below steps :

1) Open downloaded project in Visual studio
2) Goto package manager and type below command

```
  PM> Install-Package protobuf-net
```

3) Above command will generate libraries for protobuf. 
      (i) Google.ProtocolBuffers
      (ii) Google.ProtocolBuffers.Serialization

I hope this helps :)